# How can i override the http status for expired jwt when using microprofile jwt feature

Tags: open-liberty

I'm using microprofile jwt feature for role based access.   When the jwt expires I receive a 401 status code.   In order to maintain consistency with other systems here within the company I'd like to have that return a 419 status instead.   Does anyone know of a configuration way to accomplish this?   Absent configuration does anyone know of a different alternative to accomplish the same?

Thus far I've reviewed the microprofile JWT TAI implementation in the open liberty source, but I see no means to alter the expired token status code.